# Which FOSS Java application should be used in a performance test?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I would like to write an online book that shows people how to tune a Java web application by example. Using free tools, it will show people how to load test and monitor their apps so that they can make incremental performance improvements.

I already know that I want to use Jboss + Apache + Ubuntu. I don't really care whether I use MySQL or Postgresql. I also plan on using The Grinder to run my perf tests.

Now I just need to determine which Java application I want to test. Here are my high-level requirements:

- FOSS - All of the tools in my book will be FOSS to lower the costs barrier.
- It should be fairly secure - I may expose this application to the WWW, and I don't want to lose sleep over security.
- Easy to deploy - I don't want people to spend too much time deploying the app.
- Easy to load test - I would like a fairly simple UI that avoids too much Ajax.
- DB-Backed - The app has to have a RDBMS backend.

Does anyone know of a good Java app that would meet these requirements?

Comment: You might want to make it clearer that you're asking what should **be** tested, as opposed to what tools (like [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)) you would use to conduct the test.

Comment: Thanks Darien. I just made my edit.

Answer (score 1):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) might be a good choice. Simple to deploy, and it might have some future benefit as well :)

Comment: Thanks for yuor help mistagrooves, but I decided to try Jtrac instead. I like the fact that it has more "traditional" interface, and it requires a DB to run.